# MySQL table with more indexes than columns

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-workbench

I am working with an InnoDB MySQL database from MySQL workbench and am stuck on the indexes for one table.

I have a table

```
╔═══════════════╗
║  poll_votes   ║
╟───────────────╢
║pk poll_id   fk║ //references polls.id
║pk voter_id  fk║ //references users.id
║   option_id fk║ //references poll_options.id
╚═══════════════╝
```

Since the primary key is a composite key, MySQL automatically generates a multi-column index for poll_id and voter_id. Since each foreign key must have an associated index, MySQL further generates 3 additional indexes corresponding to the 3 columns.

Now I have 4 indexes on a 3-column table, and MySQL Workbench won't let me delete any of them, even though one of them is redundant. Furthermore, I'll *never* need the option_id index, so that's just wasting space.

Is having more indexes than columns going to hurt me here, or should I not worry about it? Is there a better way to design this table?

EDIT: The SQL (I edited some of the field names so there's a possibility there's a typo in here):

```
CREATE TABLE `poll_votes` (
`poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`voter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`poll_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`poll_id`,`voter_id`),
KEY `fk_poll_votes_polls1_idx` (`poll_id`),
KEY `fk_poll_votes_poll_votes1_idx` (`poll_option_id`),
KEY `fk_poll_votes_users1_idx` (`voter_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_poll_votes_polls1` FOREIGN KEY (`poll_id`) REFERENCES `polls` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_poll_votes_poll_options1` FOREIGN KEY (`poll_option_id`) REFERENCES `poll_options` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_poll_votes_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`voter_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: If you require referential integrity, you need those indexes. If you don't need referential integrity - get rid of them. Ultimately, it's just 3 columns and 4 indexes. It's really not like you have a 200 column table with 150 indexes or some other nonsense.

Comment: Since, as you pointed out, foreign keys must have an associated index, the index on option_id is needed (at very least by MySQL itself).

Comment: Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I would like to experiment with it.

Comment: @RickJames Sure, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
SET foreign_key_checks = OFF;
CREATE...
SET foreign_key_checks = ON;
```

(No, I don't understand why that flag is controlling the issue you encountered.)

Comment: Just to check, this will work without causing any instability in the database?

Comment: It is local to your session.  The worst that can happen is INSERTing foreign keys that are wrong.  But you are just CREATEing, not INSERTing.